# Android, Is it possible to use on old release version of Google Admobs dependency release?

Tags: android, admob, banner

When I try to create Google Admob banner on my project, I receive an error like this below. I want to ask that, is there a solution without changing the minSDKVersion from 14 to 17? Maybe using an old release version of google ads dependency implementation on build.gradle file? If yes, is there any drawback doing this?

Thanks..

```
Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 14 cannot be smaller than version 16 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0] C:\Users\SAMSUNG\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3f183cf0518755adc969c4fb4eee168a\jetified-play-services-ads-19.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 14
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 14,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 16,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads.impl" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Comment: Is there a strong reason you still want to support API level 14? It's 9 years old (in software terms this means ancient) and likely only running on a fraction of a percent of the devices in the wild. You'll save yourself a lot of pain if you just increase minSdkVersion.

Comment: I didn't want to restrict the number of available users, therefore searched for a solution. Maybe you are right, maybe the number is only 1% of total android users.

Comment: I believe it's much less than that.

Comment: Thank you for this info, I didn't know that:)